# How do I request a question be re-answered?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties, duplicate-questions

Say I have the question "How do I solve A". I do a search, and I find that Bob has already posted this exact question. He has also posted an answer, in which he says "I figured out I could avoid the issue by doing X", and marked correct.

However, I *can't* work around the problem. I need an actual solution to A. I can't post a new question, because then it will be immediately closed as a duplicate. But the old question is not going to get any more answers, because it already has an accepted one.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your best course of action here is to [place a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/274942) on Bob's question. There's a dialogue box that allows you to write a short message detailing what you want from answers. You could explain that you have the same problem but that the accepted answer won't work for you, so might say something like

> I've had the same issue, but the solution that [User W] gave - doing [A, B, C] - won't work for me because [X, Y, Z]. I'm looking for additional solutions that will work for my case, as well as the original situation Bob gave.

You've got no guarantee that it'll work, but you might get some real gems that'll help solve your problem. It's certainly worth a shot.